# Install will not start without nolapic

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, acpi, ubiquity

First, introduction. I am using a Dell Inspiron, 4x Intel Core i3 CPU M380@2.53 GHz, 64bit.  Currently running Kubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-116-generic.

While booting the Ubuntu-Mate 18.04 live DVD it stops, tells me the installer failed for unknown reasons, then starts a live session.  No "Welcome Screen".  I can stop the booting before the Welcome Screen by pressing a key and I see several options.  Option Live Session works but option Install fails for, again, unknown reasons.  Install option only works with nolapic active. BTW, Kubuntu installed fine 2 years ago.

Is installing even worth the effort? Will the lapic issue cause problems after install?  Considering 32bit install, upgrading bios, waiting 3–4 months.  If already discussed, please point me in the right direction.

Error message:

> The installer encountered an unrecoverable error. A desktop session will now be run so that you may investigate the problem or try installing again.

Comment: [This person with the same issue](/a/450858/175814) claims that a redownload of the ISO image and recreation of the bootable USB drive helped. You can also [boot the ISO file directly](/q/121212/175814).

Comment: I can try that, but I should add I checked the hash sums after download and write to disk. I was on my way to library to dl kubuntu anyway.

Comment: I had two versions in the first place.  bionic_desktop-amd64.iso, and ubuntu-mate-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso.

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot the live session successfully you can always run the installer from within it. The installer application name is *Ubiquity* and the executable name is `ubiquity`.

As for the kernel boot parameters (e. g. `nolapic`), you can always [edit those after the installation](/q/19486/175814) even if the boot entry in question is currently unbootable if you can boot a different Ubuntu installation or Live system.

Comment: Sorry, first thing I tried.  Gives me the same vague error message.  I haven't tried running ubiquity from a terminal, I'll try that next.  Any parameters I should know?  Right now I'm trying to get to the virtual terminal to run dmesg at the point of the error.

Comment: But back to the original question. Is it worth it? Will the installer recognize the nolapic option and install a working OS or will the computer fail each time it boots up?

Comment: @DaveWestlund: See the change to my answer.

Comment: Sometimes I worry for nothing.  Installer created a working OS despite my fervid imagination.  Someday I'm going to have to dig into the grub settings to see if the nolapic option was included automatically.